# I can't assign values to the elements of the array (using:for loop and nested if statement)

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to assign numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 to an array, but somehow I get some big numbers (AKA-Errors). My loop doesn't work. Can you tell me where am I wrong and how to fix it please?

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int i = -1;
    int arr[10];

    for ( int x = 1; x < 10; x++, i++)
    {
        if (x % 3 == 0)
        {
            arr[i + 1] = x;
        }
    }

    cout << arr[0] << endl << arr[1] << endl<< arr[3] << endl;

}
```

If I add `cout << x;` in the "if" loop, it outputs them, but it probably doesn't assign them at all. I can't figure it out.

Any ideas?

Comment: You leave parts of your array uninitialized. Also note that array indices start at `0`.

Comment: Just wondering: why are you overcomplicating your code by starting with -1 and the using i+1 ?! That just adds unnecessary complexity!

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop at least like

```
for ( int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
{
    if (x % 3 == 0)
    {
        arr[++i] = x;
    }
}
```

Otherwise `i` is changed 9 times as the variable `x` and the array has holes.

Comment: I did something similar... Actually the same, but with more code and when I reloaded the page i saw your comment. It helps alot. Thanks. I didn't think of putting ++i in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Change `[i+1]` to `[++i]`.

The first one doesn't change the value of `i` so every time you assign to the first array entry. (index 0)

//Edit:
I didn't realised you are incrementing `i` on each for loop, but as my follower said you should remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but your code does not make sense at all.

Why do you start with int i = -1;?
Why do you declare an array of size 10, if you only want 3 values?

If you want to add numbers that are dividable by 3, you don't need modulo calculations. All you do is start at 0 (or 3) and add them. However, I suppose this is some sort of exercise, so we'll do it your way.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  int arr[10];
  int x = 0; //we will check whether x is dividable by 3 or not
  for( int i = 0; i < 10; x++ ){ // note that we increment x here
    if( x % 3 == 0 ){
      arr[i] = x;
      i++; // now we increment x i.e. next time we fill in the next array element
    }
  }
  //print array
  for( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
    std::cout << "arr["<< i << "] = " << arr[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```